# Filter Nested Object and return the value along with the parent keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have an array with nested Objects with dynamic keys similar to this

```
const arr = [
      {
        "x1": [
          {
            "x1-point1": [
              {
                "value": 200,
                "angle": 20
              },
              {
                "value": 23,
                "angle": 90
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "x1-point2": [
              {
                "value": 54,
                "angle": 0
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "x1-point3": [
              {
                "value": 79
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "x2": [
          {
            "x2-point1": [
              {
                "value": 12
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "x2-point2": [
              {
                "value": 24
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            "x2-point3": [
              {
                "value": 36
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
```

Im trying to search the value and get the parent keys along with the resultant child
What i tried was this

```
val = 200
arr.filter(r => !!Object.values(r).find(t => t.value == val))
```

My expected result would be

```
[
      {
        "x1": [
          {
            "x1-point1": [
              {
                "value": 200,
                "angle": 20
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
     }
]
```

What is that im doing wrong here, Im filtering the innermost child matching with the string and getting its parent keys

Comment: Sorry, I cannot edit my comment for some reason...
So, I warned you two error: the `arr.filter()` function will be return a new array, and do not modify the original object; and the `t` variable, if you look it, every time will be a list which is after the `x1-point1` or `x2-point3` and the more smilar objects.
Sorry for my bad english speaking...

Comment: _Im filtering the innermost child_ -- not quite. The array "arr" has objects that are nested 2-levels deep. So, `arr[0]` will be the object `{"x1" : ...}`. To go to the next level, one needs to do: `arr[0].x1`. This will get access to `x1`'s value (which is an array). To access the object within that, `arr[0].x1[0]` which gets you access to object: `{ x1-point1 : [...]}`. Then, you can search like this: `arr[0].x1[0]["x1-point1"].find(....);`

Comment: @jsN00b The key values are dynamic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presented below is one possible way to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
// find needle "n" in hayStack "hs"
const myFind = (n, hs, res=[]) => {
  // search "hs" array for value "n"
  const foundIt = hs.find(ob => 'value' in ob && ob.value === n);
  
  // if found, add it to "res" array & return
  if (foundIt) {
    res.push(foundIt);
    return res;
  } else {
    // not-found - so, go to inner/nested level
    // hold result in "ires" - intermediate result array
    let ires = [];
    
    // for each object "ob" in "hs" array
    // iterate over "ob"'s key-value pairs
    // filter out pairs where "v" is not an array 
    hs.forEach(ob => {
      Object.entries(ob)
      .filter(([k, v]) => v && Array.isArray(v))
      .forEach(([k, v]) => {
        // make recursive call, this time "v" is the hayStack
        const ores = myFind(n, v);
        
        // if recursion result is present, accumulate it to "ires"
        if (ores && ores.length > 0) {
          ires.push({ [k] : ores });
        };
      })
    });
    
    // return if there is intermediate result
    if (ires.length > 0) return ires;
  };
  
  // value "n" not found
  return false;
};

const arr = [{
    "x1": [{
        "x1-point1": [{
            "value": 200,
            "angle": 20
          },
          {
            "value": 23,
            "angle": 90
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "x1-point2": [{
          "value": 54,
          "angle": 0
        }]
      },
      {
        "x1-point3": [{
          "value": 79
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "x2": [{
        "x2-point1": [{
          "value": 12
        }]
      },
      {
        "x2-point2": [{
          "value": 24
        }]
      },
      {
        "x2-point3": [{
          "value": 36
        }]
      }
    ]
  }
];

console.log('find value: 200 result: ', myFind(200, arr));
console.log('find value: 54 result: ', myFind(54, arr));
console.log('find value: 36 result: ', myFind(36, arr));
console.log('find value: 205 result: ', myFind(205, arr));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

**Explanation**

Inline comments added to the snippet above.

PS: If you'd like to add value to stackoverflow community,

> Please consider reading: [What to do when my question is answered](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)
>  Thank you !